# How to use navGraphViewModels in Activity (Not in Fragment)

Tags: android, navigation, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

In Fragment, we can use ViewModel scoped to navigation Graph.

```
private val viewModel: ViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.youNavGraphID)
```

But how to create ViewModel with navGraph scope in **Activity**? Or is it any way to make the ViewModel scoped to navigation graph in **Activity**? I need to recreate the ViewModel object instance after the navigation graph is destroyed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very late answer but hopefully it helps someone else.

You can use a ViewModelProvider with the ViewModelStoreOwner of the NavigationController.

Basically like this:

```
val myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
    navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(navGraphId), 
    defaultViewModelProviderFactory
)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```